# How to get curl response in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

```
$ch = curl_init();

//Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
  CURLOPT_URL => $ls,
  CURLOPT_NOBODY => 1,
  CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC, 
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => $user . ":" . $password, 
  CURLOPT_HTTPGET => TRUE //Set cURL to GET method
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($data);
```

Currently I am getting this:

```
<smslist> <error> <smsclientid>0</smsclientid> <error-code>-10002</error-code> <error-description>Invalid Username Or Password</error-description> <error-action>1</error-action> </error> </smslist>
```

I want to store error-description alone in a  table. How can I get error-description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get error description using regex:

```php
$matches = array();
// we use ? because we want to stop at first </error-description>
// we use preg_match because we want only one error-description text
preg_match('/<error-description>(.+?)<\/error-description>/', $data, $matches);
$errorDescription = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
```

Because it seems you have an XML response you could try an XML parser, but I think this is an easier solution.

Hope I helped. :)